# Sitecore How to Get Control's Data Source Value

Tags: sitecore, datasource

Is it possible to get __Rendering control's template field value on content item?
Especially, I'd like to get "Data Source" field value defined in control on page item, like below screenshot.

As shown in screenshot, I have some controls in page item and I'd like to get control's "Data Source" field value.

[image]

I used this code and I could list all controls using on the page item. But, I don't know how to get the control's browsed data-source information on the page.

```csharp
public RenderingReference[] GetListOfSublayouts(string itemId, Item targetItem)
{
    RenderingReference[] renderings = null;

    if (Sitecore.Data.ID.IsID(itemId))
    {
        renderings = targetItem.Visualization.GetRenderings(Sitecore.Context.Device, true);
    }

    return renderings;
}

public List<RenderingItem> GetListOfDataSource(RenderingReference[] renderings)
{
    List<RenderingItem> ListOfDataSource = new List<RenderingItem>();
    foreach (RenderingReference rendering in renderings)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(rendering.Settings.DataSource))
        {
            ListOfDataSource.Add(rendering.RenderingItem);
        }
    }
    return ListOfDataSource;
}


RenderingReference[] renderings = GetListOfSublayouts(targetItem.ID.ToString(), targetItem);
List<RenderingItem> ListOfDataSource = GetListOfDataSource(renderings);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what I wanted.

**Perfectly working!!!!!!**

```csharp
public IEnumerable<string> GetDatasourceValue(Item targetItem)
{
    List<string> uniqueDatasourceValues = new List<string>();
    Sitecore.Layouts.RenderingReference[] renderings = GetListOfSublayouts(targetItem.ID.ToString(), targetItem);
    foreach (var rendering in renderings)
    {
        if (!uniqueDatasourceValues.Contains(rendering.Settings.DataSource))
            uniqueDatasourceValues.Add(rendering.Settings.DataSource);
        }

        return uniqueDatasourceValues;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a blog post that can help: [Using the Data Source Field with Sitecore Sublayouts](http://firebreaksice.com/using-the-datasource-field-with-sitecore-sublayouts/)

Here's the relevant code you can call from within a single control:

```csharp
private Item _dataSource = null;
public Item DataSource
{
    get
    {
        if (_dataSource == null)
            if(Parent is Sublayout)
                _dataSource = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(((Sublayout)Parent).DataSource);

        return _dataSource;
    }
}
```

Accesing the `DataSource` property defined above will give you the item that is assigned as the Data Source from the CMS.

Comment: I used the code, but when I add a condition, **if (DataSource == null)**, it is true. How to define the page item so that it can be the parent item. I don't directly access the sublayout because this is additional assembly working with workflow pipeline.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you re-phrase it?

Comment: Mark, I posted my answer and it is perfectly working. To get the list of controls on the page, renderingReferece and IEnumerable Interface are the key points.